# Appsflyer DeeplinkListener takes too long to execute callback =

Tags: android, deep-linking, appsflyer, appsflyer-android-sdk

I implemented Appsflyer DeeplinkListener in my application.
The main problem is that it takes about 2 minutes to perform action in a callback.

There is only one activity that is exported and has set intent filter, as per Appsflyer guide.

Is there any way to solve this?